# How do I create an Apache Ambari view using existing source code?

Tags: view, visualization, ambari

I'm currently a developer working on a project to better visualize big data analytics in Apache Ambari views.

I read through the documentation here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Views

I have some existing source code written in HTML, CSS, and PHP and need some help in compiling the compatible jar file that is compatible with Ambari Views.

I see the source tree and understand that I need to use Maven to compile my source into the jar file utilizing the proper XML

In the documentation there are multiple examples that do not compile with Maven. I receive the error, "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (PRIVATE). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]"

Even if I change the view.xml to a pom.xml it still produces errors.
How can I compile it correctly and display as an Ambari View?

Answer (score 0):

view.xml documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/View+Definition

for compiling Maven you need a seperate pom.xml file. The main difference is that instead of `<project>` you might want to use `<view>`

Here's an example of the pom.xml file I used that compiled it correctly:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

NOTE: This is not the proper way to make a POM file but it will compile and help you find the right direction

My file tree is as follows:

```
view-folder
|
|_docs
  |
  |-readme.txt
|
|-pom.xml
|
|_src
  |
  |_main
    |
    |_resources
      |
      |{source: included the view.xml here}
```

There is probably a more elegant answer, but I'm doing something related so if I find a better answer as I'm developing I'll update this.

I also suggest using jQuery or AJAX instead of PHP since some builds of Ambari might not support PHP but I think most browsers natively support javascript.